# Transform a snippet from C to C#

Tags: c#, c, migration

How do I transform the following code into C#. My C is a little bit rusty:

```
short CalcCrc(char *str,int len)
{
  short crc=0;
  for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    crc ^= (short)((unsigned char)str[i]) << (i%9);
  return crc;
}
```

Comment: Many will refuse to do your homework, as will I.

Comment: @Marcel Gheorghita: It's not homework, I'm helping a friend and I'm not sure on casting (diferent data types c and c#)

Comment: You have the same operators in C#. Short is short. Unsigned char is byte. char* is string.

Comment: @Marcel Gheorghita:
I'm thinking like this. I'm missing something?

crc ^= Convert.ToInt16(Convert.ToByte(str[i]) << (i % 9));

Comment: It seems fine. Are you receiving different results?

Comment: @Marcel Gheorghita: It's working. Thank you for suport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    short CalcCrc(string str)
    {
        short crc = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            crc ^= (short)(str[i] << (i % 9));
        return crc;
    }
```